# Symfony, arrange controllers into a "wizard"?

Tags: symfony, wizard

I have a number of [Symfony](http://symfony.com/) Controllers, that all currently redirect from one to another, forming a chain of forms, much like an installation [wizard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wizard_%28software%29) might.

Controller X being hardcoded to redirect to Controller Y, makes changing the code later much more tedious and error prone.

I'm looking to replace these hardcoded redirects with some form form of wrapping class that will allow me to more dynamically build the list of controllers.

Is such a library already available, or do I need to write it from scratch?

Answer (score 2):

You can [search for a bundle with the `flow` keyword](http://knpbundles.com/search?q=flow). I've been using CraueFormFlowBundle and it did the job.

Comment: Thanks, I suspected my problem was my search terms. Thanks, I'll look into those.